# Why the emails aren't be sent with Fresh Magento 2 installation?

Tags: magento2, email, transactional-mail, third-party-module

I've installed Fresh Magento 2.0.0, but I'm not receiving **Email on Registration** and on **Placing New order**.

Is there any setting to start transactional emails?

Comment: Do you have a working cronjob setup for the store?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You need configure email setting then only send email to ordered account

Open your **Admin panel-> Store -> Configuration -> System-> Email setting** then write your email host and port number.

then click **Save Configuration**.

Now, order or create a new account then customer receive new email from magento2 admin.

Answer (score 0):

Ther are several error possibilities. What OS are YOU using? If Unix please try following: 
 mail -s testmail receiver@yourmail.com 
Testmessage
.

If your message doesn't arrive you first need to configure your system mail Transport agent.

Answer (score 0):

If on linux, make sure you have sendmail installed on the server.

Also, if not using the default templates. Check your spam folders. I had all my email go straight to spam and didn't realize it for a while.